# How can I structure these kodi parameter checks?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kodi

I'm creating an add-on for Kodi and am in the middle of restructuring the directory structure and `router` function as my programmatic flow and features have drastically changed since first starting the project. The new directory structure I'm looking to implement goes like so:

- By Animal

  - Animal 1 (eg Cats)

    - Suggested Category/Search 1 (eg Cats on Roombas)
    - Suggested Category/Search 2 (eg Cats & Cucumbers)
    - All
    - By Site
    - Random Video
    - Random Continuous
    - Search
  - Animal 2

    - Suggested Category/Search 1
    - Suggested Category/Search 2
    - All
    - By Site
    - Random Video
    - Random Continuous
    - Search
- By Site

  - Site 1 (Active)
  - Site 2 (Dormant)
  - Site 3 (Active/Large Selection)
  - Site 4 (Dormant/Large Selection)
- By Category

  - Educational/Wildlife

    - All
    - By Animal
    - By Site
    - Random Video
    - Random Continuous
    - Search
  - Heartwarming

    - All
    - By Animal
    - By Site
    - Random Video
    - Random Continuous
    - Search
  - Cute/Funny

    - All
    - By Animal
    - By Site
    - Random Video
    - Random Continuous
    - Search
- Live Streams
- Random Video
- Random Continuous
- Global Search

As you can see there are some repeating directory items, which I intend of having to allow users to refine their searches as they get deeper into the directory structure. Those repeating items are where I'm currently lost pertaining to how to deal with them. My reworked `router` function currently looks like this:

```
MAIN_MENU = ['By Animal',
             'By Site',
             'By Category',
             'Live Streams',
             'Random Video',
             'Random Continuous',
             'Search']

def get_url(**kwargs):
    return '{0}?{1}'.format(_url, urlencode(kwargs))

def main_menu():
    for menu_item in MAIN_MENU:
        list_item = xbmcgui.ListItem(label=menu_item)
        is_folder = True
        url = get_url(action='listing', section=menu_item)
        xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(_handle, url, list_item, is_folder)
    xbmcplugin.addSortMethod(_handle, xbmcplugin.SORT_METHOD_NONE)
    xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(_handle)

def router(paramstring):
    params = dict(parse_qsl(paramstring))
    if params:
        if params['action'] == 'listing':
            if 'topic' in params:
                meta.get_directory(params['section'], params['topic'])
            else:
                meta.get_directory(params['section'])
        elif params['action'] == 'query':
            if 'section' in params:
                #further checks
                if 'topic' in params:
                    #Only search sources under this topic (suggested category, all, by site, random video, etc)
                    #meta.get_results(params['section'], params['topic'], params['query'])
                elif 'animal' in params:
                    #Only search sources with this animal in their meta tags
            else:
                #global search
                #scraper.Site.search(params['QUERY'])
        elif params['action'] == 'play':
            
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid paramstring: {0}!'.format(paramstring))
    else:
        main_menu()
```

Obviously it's a pretty big mess right now. I feel like it's stuck in an infinite loop. I have what I think should be the parameters worked out in my head, but am not sure how to correctly implement them to recursively work with the directory structure above.

---

## Parameter List

- **ACTION**:

  1. *listing* (by section, then by topic)
  2. *query* (by section [checks if global search], by source, by animal, by term/query)
  3. *play* (link has been retrieved, play it)
- **SECTION**: which directory we're in (By Animal, By Site, By Category, etc)
- **TOPIC**: which subdirectory is selected from the section (Animal 1 under By Animal, Cute/Funny under By Category, etc)
- **ANIMAL**?: which animal we've selected or are in
- **SOURCE**?: which source we've selected or are in
- **QUERY**: contains the search term
- **VIDEO**: contains the link to play

---

## Finally, the questions

- Is it possible to make this structure work?

  - If so, how?
- In what order do I need to check the parameters in order to cover all the possibilities?
- Should I structure this differently in order for it to work?

  - If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

For complex path hierarchy I'd recommend not to invent a wheel but use this routing library: https://github.com/tamland/kodi-plugin-routing . It's `script.module.routing` in the Kodi official addon repository.

This library creates "pretty" URLs with arbitrary paths much like popular Flask web framework, doing all heavy lifting like paths parsing "under the hood".

Copy-paste from the library's Readme:

```
import routing
from xbmcgui import ListItem
from xbmcplugin import addDirectoryItem, endOfDirectory

plugin = routing.Plugin()

@plugin.route('/')
def index():
    addDirectoryItem(plugin.handle, plugin.url_for(show_category, "one"), ListItem("Category One"), True)
    addDirectoryItem(plugin.handle, plugin.url_for(show_category, "two"), ListItem("Category Two"), True)
    endOfDirectory(plugin.handle)

@plugin.route('/category/<category_id>')
def show_category(category_id):
    addDirectoryItem(plugin.handle, "", ListItem("Hello category %s!" % category_id))
    endOfDirectory(plugin.handle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plugin.run()
```